# How would you say "as what is Britain perceived"?

Tags: grammar, translation

I'd like to know which verb to use for "perceive" in this context. Dictionary gives me "empfinden" and "wahrnehmen". Also, how to say "as what". I know "**was**" is but not sure whether "als was" is correct.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. New edit(s) should clarify question. If not, don't worry. Grantwalzer has answered my questions and if you want to close this post, then go ahead. Thanks for your help and I'll be clearer next time!

Comment: No issue here... :) The best thank you you can give on this site is to "accept" an answer (and of course to upvote it as soon as you have enough reputation to do so). Cleared all comments for clean-up. Do continue to ask (and answer whenever you can).

Comment: I retracted my downvote. Question is much better now. Thanks for editing. – I'm not sure if I really *perceive* what the English sentence implies, but I would go with a much simpler translation: "Als was Briten *gesehen* werden". Both "wahrnehmen" and "empfinden" doesn't sound right to me (in this context). I might be wrong but it's hard to tell without context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally:

> Als was werden wir Briten [von anderen] wahrgenommen?
>   Als was wird das Vereinigte Königreich wahrgenommen?

The suggested phrase conveys perception on a more emotional level, like "How do other people feel about what we do?":

> Als was werden wir Briten empfunden?
>   Als was wird das Vereinigte Königreich empfunden?

Another possibility is to use "how" instead:

> Wie werden wir Briten wahrgenommen/empfunden?

Comment: Thanks very much, much appreciated. I'll use the final possibility (Wie werden wir ...).

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde hier einen Anglizismus verwenden:

> Wie ist das allgemeine [Image](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Image) von England?

Comment: You posts often are flagged for the "low quality review" from the community robot - please don't just post a single-liner. This can be avoided by adding formatting or links e.g. to a dictionary entry,  Wikipedia, a quote for common usage, related posts here, or else. Thank you.